# ReactJS: How to print html symbols within expressions

Tags: reactjs

### Goal (abstract)

I want that `{'&lt;'}` gets rendered as `<` and not as `&lt;`.

### Actual problem at hand:

```
let value1 = '&lt;'
let value2 = '&gt;'

return (<div>
            {mycondition ? value1 : value2}
        </div>
       )
```

### I've tried

I've tried `{<>&lt;</>}` and `<>{&lt;}</>`, but both didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that it's interpreting the strings as actual text rather than HTML entities, so they're being escaped before rendering.

As per [Mr.Gandhi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72371485/19176369) answer, you probably want to wrap them in a React fragment so that they are treated as actual HTML entities. Don't forget you can also store JSX values in variables, so your code could be reformatted to:

```
let value1 = <>&lt;</>;
let value2 = <>&gt;</>;

return (<div>
        {mycondition ? value1 : value2}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{<>&#60;</>} //<--- This will print <

{<>&#62;</>} //<--- This will print >
```